# Put html circle beside a div and paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I have this html code that consists of a circle shape and 2 text `div` and `p` tag. What I'm trying to accomplish is like this picture below. I tried adding an inline-block in my circle and in my `h1` and `p` but it just end up in a weird position. I'm not sure if I am doing it the right way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #16444d;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #053740;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #919191;
}

.header-step {
  display: table;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-step ">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <h1>Some very very long header</h1>
    <p>He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting<br> and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable,<br> and he had indeed the vaguest
      idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the CSS `Flexbox`.

Here I've added `display: flex` to the container `.header-step` and `flex-shrink: 0` to the `.circle` to ensure it maintains its shape.

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #16444d;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #053740;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #919191;
}

.header-step {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-step ">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <h1>Some very very long header</h1>
    <p>He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting<br> and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable,<br> and he had indeed the vaguest
      idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `flex`.

- set `display: flex;` to `header-step` which is the parent
- use `flex: 0 85%;` in which you have set inline `display:
  inline-block;`
- remove `top-margin` of `h1`

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #16444d;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
h1{
    font-weight: 700;
    color:#053740;
    font-size:30px;
}
p{
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #919191;
 }
 .header-step{
    display: table;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:25px;
    display: flex; /* Added */
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;/* Added */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div class= "header-step ">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;flex: 0 85%;"><!-- Added CSS here -->
    <h1>Some very very long header<h1>
    <p>He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting </br>and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable,
</br>and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```css
.text {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  vertical-align:top;
}
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #16444d;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: -5px;
}
h1{
    font-weight: 700;
    color:#053740;
    font-size:30px;
}
p{
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #919191;
 }
 .header-step{
    display: table;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div class= "header-step ">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;" class='text'>
    <h1>Some very very long header<h1>
            <p>He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting </br>and
                fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable,
                </br>and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve it with minimal changes to your code, I would like to tell you the logic behind inline-block.

ParentDIV has display: block

Child1DIV has display: inline-block

Child2DIV has display: inline-block

Child1DIV and Child2DIV will be "inline"d on the same block "ParentDIV"

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #16444d;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #053740;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #919191;
}

.header-step {
  display: table;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.circle-text{

    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-step ">
  <div class="top-header">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div class="circle-text"><h1>Some very very long header</h1></div>
  </div>

    <p>He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting<br> and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable,<br> and he had indeed the vaguest
      idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: PS: I know flex could've been used, similar to other answers, however I've always noticed Flex and Flexbox have issues with compatibility with older browsers, so I tend to avoid it unless I have no other logical answer.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try with `position:absolute` element and add some `padding-left` value for the text box.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #16444d;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 65px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #053740;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #919191;
}

.header-step {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-step ">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Some very very long header
        <h1>
          <p>He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting </br>and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable,
            </br>and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:before`  pseudo-class for this, in combination with data-attributes it becomes quite powerful I think. Notice i added a class to the `h1` elements that are supposed to get a circle.

```css
h1{
        font-weight: 700;
        color:#053740;
        font-size:30px;
    }
h1.circle:before{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #16444d;
        display: inline-block;
        content:attr(data-num);
        margin-right:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="circle" data-num="1">Some very very long header</h1>
<h1 class="circle" data-num="2">Second header</h1>
```